# как избавиться от наезда блока на блок в меню?

Tags: html, css, scss

Как избавиться от наезда одного блока на другой, когда используешь `width` в процентах и еще `display:flex`?

```css
.menu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: #212121;
  position: fixed;
}
.menu .logo {
  width: 15%;
  margin: auto 0 auto 3%;
  padding: 3px 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background-color: #e01f3d;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.menu ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 5% 0 auto;
}
.menu ul li {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.menu ul li a {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 2vw;
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu">
    <a href="main.php" class="logo">RockstarFM</a>

    <ul>
        <li><a href="main.php">Главная</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Услуги</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Галерея</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Дополнительные инструменты</a></li>
        <li><a href="contactus.php">Контакты</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: flex-wrap: wrap

Comment: @soledar10 СПАСИБО!!!